# Are the following statements?

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus

I started reading Logic. I am little confused whether the following are proposition or not.

1) Sum of two complex number is complex number

2)Sum of a real and a complex number will always be complex number,

3) If $x\in A \cup B$ , then $x \in B$

4) If $x\in A \cap B$ , then $x \in B$

my try----

1) This statement is true for all complex number. So the statement is true for any subset of complex number. So this is STATEMENT / PROPOSITION.

2) similar as (1). So STATEMENT.

3)This is not a STATEMENT.

4)This is true for any $A$ and $B$ so this is always true. No need to specify. This is a STATEMENT.

Can you please correct me if I go wrong anywhere?

Thank You.

Comment: If you are trying to reason and understand the cases, you are correct about all of that. But if you want to prove any of those, you need to write it in mathematical terms.

Comment: What to write to prove those are statements? Can you please explain any one of them?@MehrdadZandigohar

Comment: Case $2$: $(ai+b)+(c)=(b+c)+ai ∈ Z$, $a$ can never be zero, otherwise it was not complex at first place. So it is always complex.

Comment: 3) and 4) have the same "logical form": the only difefrence is that 3) is FALSE while 4) is TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

2) is not a proposition because of 'would', that means that statement can not be only true or only false (not both) since it's ambiguous, you don't know what it's exactly saying, although it could work in some mathematical system in which 'would' is defined, say a statistics environment.
3) defines implicity $A$ and $B$ as sets, the fact that, in general is false just means that, but of course it's a proposition with the value 'false'.

Comment: statement 2) is always true.

Comment: @cmi it is always true and the word "would" is a little bit misleading! why did it use would instead of will? I am agreeing with Tobias (+1 for that).

Comment: edited@MehrdadZandigohar

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mistaken about number $3.$  Just as in number $4,$ A and B are understood to be sets, and the usual interpretation of the statement in mathematics is that whatever sets A and B may be, the conclusion is true.  This is not the case, so it a false statement.

Comment: I think this will not be a STATEMENT. As if I restrict the domain of $A$ and $B$ as $A$ is any non-empty set and $B$ is empty , in this domain that was true. But if I say $A$ and $B$ can be any set, then that was false..